# Laravel Route shows 404

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I had this Laravel in my web.php which was working. But right now, the route shows a 404 page.

> This is not working now.And I want this route.

The broken route

```
Route::get('/b/{business}/jobs/create', 'JobController@create')->name('dashboard_job_create');
```

> This route was working fine.

The route that I changed it to in order to make it work

```
Route::get('/b/{business}/1212/create', 'JobController@create')->name('dashboard_job_create');
```

The problem now is that I want the route to have "jobs" instead of "1212", but the route with "jobs" isn't working anymore.

Comment: you changed 'jobs' in old to '1212' in new. Is that intended?

Comment: The "jobs" didn't work anymore. But when I changed it to "1212", the route started working again

Comment: Maybe it has something todo with the order of routes. Some routes can't be before others. Even the method matters.

Comment: what is 1212 its an id?? Did you change the url in view page

Comment: @SuperDJ that seems to have fixed the problem, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to check the order of the routes. Some routes can't be before other routes. The route method ( `put`, `get`, etc ) also matters.

Apparently it has something todo with the specifity of the route: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/order-of-routes-in-webphp?page=1